# Adding git commit message to all files (even unchanged) 

Tags: git, github

I would like to update every single file's commit message within GitHub at certain times.

Whenever I make a major upgrade (merging development into stable branch), I would like to commit and push my changes to GitHub such that all of the files, even those which have had no changes, have the same commit message.

**Example:**

- Development is tested and ready to be merged into Master
- Development is merged into master
- Commit message "New Version: 2.0" is applied to all files (even unchanged files)
- Master branch is pushed to remote (GitHub)
- GitHub displays the same message ("New Version: 2.0") across every single file/directory

I *could* go through every file and add a newline to the end of the file, but I feel as though there may be a way to do this from git or github itself.

Comment: Why? That's not the point of source-control *at all*

Comment: It's specific to the way GitHub displays data, is all.

Comment: I love how none of the answers actually provide any *real* answer to this question. Regardless of whether or not the OP is asking something that shouldn't be done, answers should include the solution to do what the OP asked, or clearly state "This isn't possible".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to track a point in time for things like released, use a tag instead. Don't "hack" the commit process like you suggest. How would you then find the real diff between checks?

Comment: I was **not** suggesting, but trying to clearly explain the objective I wish to accomplish.  I'll look into **tags**.  I think that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

That's simply not how git works, adding nonsense to the history of all files is likely to be very counter productive whenever you need to review it.

You might find [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to be a useful read. You don't have to use it - but the explanation of workflow may help you understand how better to use git.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  What I want to do is something cosmetic.  Your link has shown me that **tags** are what I'm looking for.